# How do I fix my html/javascript code to animate a sprite sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sprite, sprite-sheet

I attempted to animate a sprite sheet using html and javascript to no avail. Here is my sprite sheet

[image]

Below is lines 36-59 of my code. I'm not getting any errors so I don't really know what's wrong. How do I fix/improve my code?

This is for a project I'm doing. I've tried using different methods I've found online but none really worked either. I've tried shifting the image as well.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tree Animation</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>

        <script>

            var canWidth = 400;
            var canHeight = 100;

            //position where the frame will be drawn
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;

            var srcX;
            var srcY;

            var sheetWidth = 230;
            var sheetHeight = 79;

            var frameCount = 5;

            var width = sheetWidth/frameCount;
            var height;

            var currentFrame = 0;

            var tree = new Image();
            tree.src = "tree sprite.jpg"

            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            canvas.width = canWidth;
            canvas.height = canHeight;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            function updateFrame(){
                currentFrame = ++currentFrame%frameCount

                srcX = currentFrame*width;
                srcY = 0;

                ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
            }

            function draw(){
                updateFrame();

            }

            setInterval(function(){
                draw();
            }, 100);

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I expect the output to be an animation of a tree growing, but instead I'm getting a blank page.

Comment: Hi, would be helpful if you could provide a working demo, thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prashantram/cbf6syjb/5/ this is kind of what I want to achieve

Comment: There are too many errors in your code. Please open your browser's dev-tools javascript console. Fix all the errors you find there (first it will complain about undefined variables, then against `ctx.draw` which is not a function, then maybe about sourceimage being in a broken state etc.) Once this is done, it will be the time to ask for help. But until there are such errors thrown in the console, you are supposed to fixed it, or to ask a question specifically about the error if you can't find how to fix it.

Comment: I updated the code again and fixed the errors you mentioned. I have no errors showing up and it still shows a blank page.

Comment: When I said to fix the errors, I didn't meant remove the lines where the errors are thrown. For instance, `height` is still undefined, now it's declared and won't throw, but still you can't use it in ctx.clearRect, it will make this call do nothing. `ctx.draw` was not a function, but you do need something to draw your image on your canvas (it is `ctx.drawImage`) etc.

Comment: Okay got it! Instead of 
        'ctx.draw'
I used 
       'ctx.drawImage'
. I also gave 'height'
a value. I got the imaged to animate, I just need to play around with the dimensions. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

you should provide more code or a snippet, there are several variables didn't show up in your code

and it's hard to debug your code if u use setInterval, you should make sure your code can work first.

maybe you can try step by step:

1. draw the whole img on the canvas first. if it works, go next
2. invoke your `draw()` function manually, check if the img drawed
3. invoke more, such as`setTimout(draw, 1000)`, check the result

ok, and i think you can `console.log` these variables in `draw`

Comment: I'm kind of a beginner, can you explain what you mean by drawing the whole img on the canvas? (I updated my code above)

Comment: you need check the document of `drawImage` : [https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)